# Custom validator causes StackOverflowException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, check-constraints

i want to implement `ConstraintsValidator` which verifies whether an email is available before registering a new user, using spring’s depandency injection `@Autowired` to inject JPA Repository in the validator to make database search.

i so changed hibernate’s validator factory so that spring instanciate the validator so that i can use `@Autowired`

Everything works fine, however it’s like the validation is entering a infinite loop which causes a `stackoverflowexception`.

Note: lthe validation is done automatically (i’m not calling `validator.validate()`) as i’m using REST JPA Repository

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@UniqueCompteEmail
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Compte implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5230227676515387462L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String password;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract CompteType getTypeCompte();

    public abstract void setTypeCompte(CompteType typeCompte);

    public static enum CompteType {
        ETUDIANT, ADMINISTRATEUR
    }
}

@Repository
public interface CompteRepository extends JpaRepository<Compte, Integer> {

    public Optional<Compte> findByUsername(String username);

    public Optional<Compte> findByEmail(String email);
}

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueCompteEmailValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface UniqueCompteEmail {

    String message() default "{com.mssmfactory.bacsimulator.uniquecompteemail.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class UniqueCompteEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueCompteEmail, Compte> {

    @Autowired
    private CompteRepository compteRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueCompteEmail constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Compte value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value != null) {
            Optional<Compte> compte = this.compteRepository.findByEmail(value.getEmail());

            return !compte.isPresent();
        } else
            return false;
    }
}

@Component
public class ValidatorAddingCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        if (validatorFactory != null) {
            hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validatorFactory);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't define any events, the validator would be called for all of events.

The events are (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events)):

> - BeforeCreateEvent
> - AfterCreateEvent
> - BeforeSaveEvent
> - AfterSaveEvent
> - BeforeLinkSaveEvent
> - AfterLinkSaveEvent
> - BeforeDeleteEvent
> - AfterDeleteEvent

And because you are going to fetch in validating method from db, you're trapped in an infinite loop.

You just need to annotate the validator by a convectional name.

```java
@Component("beforeCreateCompteValidator")
public UniqueCompteEmailValidator implements Validator<Compte>{
}
```

and removing other annotations.

Spring recognizes this validator and attached to the right hook.

For more information see [Spring Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation)

Comment: Clear answer (y)